# Autofac - Configure Module List-Property with object

Tags: autofac, autofac-module, autofac-configuration

I want to configure per XML a module with a property, which contains a list of class MyObject.
My Module and MyObject class are looking like:

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
    public IList<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        // Do something with MyObjects.
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisable { get; set; }
}
```

My assumption was to configure it like this in XML:

```
<modules name="MyModule">
<type>...</type>
<properties>
  <MyObjects>
    <MyObject>
      <Id>1234</Id>
      <IsVisilble>false</IsVisilble>
    </MyObject>
  </MyObjects>
</properties>
```

But if I run this, I get the following exception:

```
Unable to convert object of type 'Autofac.Configuration.Util.ConfiguredDictionaryParameter' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[MyObject]'
```

I'm using Autofac 4.5.0 with Autofac.Configuration 4.0.1.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get it working?

Comment: Core Autofac doesn't come with config support, that's a separate package. Include which version of that you're using. Also, [have you read the docs?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html)

Comment: @TravisIllig Yes I read the docs. I'm using autofac.configuration.4.0.1

Comment: Any typos in your stuff? `IsVisable` (in code) vs `IsVisilble` (in XML)? Did you [look at the examples in the unit tests](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/blob/develop/test/Autofac.Configuration.Test/Files/ConfigurationExtensions_EnumerableParameters.xml)? Looks like your `name` on the module isn't a number - that's a problem. Looks like you're missing `name` on the elements in your list - that's a problem. Try JSON instead of XML, it's way easier to work with.